# how to create circle in Bing maps like in gmaps "google.maps.Circle"

Tags: bing-maps

function addCircles(location,radius,name) {
            var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                center: location,
                radius: radius
            });
            circles.push(cityCircle); 
i am createing circle like this in gmaps is there simiar kindof option in bing maps???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools for creating circles in Bing Maps. The most common is to use the getRegularPolygon function in the [spatial math module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt750541.aspx) to generate the locations for a circle and then you can create either a polyline or a polygon from it. Here are a bunch of related code samples:

- http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#SpatialMath_Circles
- http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#SpatialMath_DrawCircle
- http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#DrawingTools_CustomToolbar
- http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#SpatialMath_AccuracyCircle

Note that there is a source code button in the top right corner of all the samples.